# Automatically access the camera without asking for permission

Tags: javascript, webrtc, mediarecorder-api

I am using Media Recorder to record the video and audio from the camera. Each time I start recording It asks for the permissions.

Is it possible to automatically take the user access to the camera.

I am using the below code to get the camera access.

```
 navigator.getMedia = (navigator.getUserMedia ||
          navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
          navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
          navigator.msGetUserMedia);


  if (!navigator.getMedia) {
      displayErrorMessage("Your browser doesn't have support for the navigator.getUserMedia interface.");
  } else {

      // Request the camera.
      navigator.getMedia(
              constraints,
              // Success Callback
                      function (stream) {

}
```

Comment: You can go into your browser settings and change it for yourself. You can't force this on other users as this is under the browsers control - not Javascript.

Comment: Doesn't the browser have the option to "remember" the decision to allow access? Tick that box, and you'll be fine from then on

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible to do , and considered as violating the user privacy , most of browsers / devices would ask for the user to allow accessing into camera.

[this page explains how](https://blog.teamtreehouse.com/accessing-the-device-camera-with-getusermedia) to do this but it will ask for the user permission to allow cam view

however , the only way you can do that by using **internet explorer** browser through ActiveX libraries

in addition , there could be a way to achieve this by tricking the user once he visit your website and ask him directly that this website might getting full access / control  to the PC without specifying  the camera message which again against rules and will be considered as violating users privacy .

Answer (score 0):

It is possible on the mobile web! y asking the browser to pick up a file from the file browser, at the mobile web the browser usually uses the camera to do it. See https://austingil.com/html-capture-attribute/ for more details.